# Install patch file in Redmine for windows

Tags: windows, patch, redmine

I want to install a patch file in Windows server for redmine. When executing in cmd:
patch -p0 < file.patch
I get the error: patch commmand not found

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Patch takes a patch file containing a difference listing produced by the diff program and applies those differences to one or more original files, producing patched versions.

It's native to unix/linux os-es, but for Windows, you need to install patch.exe and add it to system's or user's environment variable PATH

Probably best way is to install 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm

On Windows it differs from version to version, but it looks somewhat like this:

1. From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
2. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab
3. In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
4. Then, in the Environment Variables window, edit the Path variable in the Systems Variable.
5. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish your console to access. Directories are separated with a semicolon as shown below.

   > C:\Program Files\; C:\Windows\System32

Example of path location in windows : C:\util\patch\

Comment: I finally managed to install the Gnuwin, NOw when I try to install the patch file I get an error from the file :                                                  
_ can't find file to patch at input line 4_
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|*** diff -Naur app/models/issue.rb
--------------------------
File to patch:

Comment: Well you need to modify path or run patch from proper directory. It says it can't find file that needs to be patched...

Comment: I copied the patch file into the redmine root folder where I am running the commmand, but still getting the same error. Do I need any other files ?

Comment: You need patch executable, then run patch's filename as argument.

Comment: What do you mean by patch executable?I have the patch.exe form the GnuWin program.Do I need to copy these exe file in the same directory where I have the .patch file?. What i do is run the command:                                                            patch -p0 < filename.patch

Comment: Yes, if it's not in your path... When you type patch.exe -v it should give you version.

Comment: When I run patch.exe -v from the directory where I have the patch executable I get the version. However when I run the same command from the redmine directory I get nothing. So I updated the path variable in the system Environment variables : PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin, but still unable to run the command. What am I doing wrong?